# Is rotation broken in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to have a diamond shaped box with some text inside and do a flipping card effect on hover. I have tried multiple ways to achieve this effect and Firefox was the only one failing every time with similar effect happening.

Heres the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vHL38/

This issue can be fixed only when commenting out this line:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
```

in the .flipper .bg class, but I would rather keep the cross-browser consistency.

Thank you for you answers!

Comment: What exactly do you see as Firefox failing? I tried the fiddle with Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu. On Chromium, I see that on hover the diamond flips and turns to light gray and displays "Test". On Firefox, the diamond flips but is still the same color, and the text disappears. I tried commenting `-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);`, but see no difference.

Comment: Ok, I had an older version of Firefox at work and that was the reason it was not working. My code still has a minor bug but I guess it's easy to fix.

I apologize, my concentration is a bit low atm.